# MSB3073 error while trying to build a vst3 project

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I was trying to build a vst3 project using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 but it seems something went wrong. I can't find anything helpfull by searching on the Internet so I'm asking for your help.

Any idea what exactly went wrong and what I should do to fix it ?

Visual Studio is trying to communicate:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/VST_SDK/vst3sdk/cmake/module/../templates/VST_Logo_Steinberg.ico "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/PlugIn.ico"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/VST_SDK/vst3sdk/cmake/modules/../templates/desktop.ini.in "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/desktop.ini"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
attrib +s "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/desktop.ini"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
attrib +s "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/PlugIn.ico"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
attrib +s "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
setlocal
cd "C:\Users\brieu\Desktop\Test CMake\Test\build\bin"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Users\brieu\Desktop\Test CMake\Test\build\bin\Debug\moduleinfotool.exe" -create -version 1.0.0.0 -path "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3" -output "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/Contents/Resources/moduleinfo.json"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
setlocal
cd "C:\Users\brieu\Desktop\Test CMake\Test\build\bin"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
C:
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo [SMTG] Validator started...
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Users\brieu\Desktop\Test CMake\Test\build\bin\Debug\validator.exe" "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3/Contents/x86_64-win/test.vst3"
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo [SMTG] Validator finished.
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo [SMTG] Delete previous link...
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -rf C:/Users/brieu/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/VST3/test.vst3
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo [SMTG] Creation of the new link...
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E create_symlink "C:/Users/brieu/Desktop/Test CMake/Test/build/VST3/Debug/test.vst3"  C:/Users/brieu/AppData/Local/Programs/Common/VST3/test.vst3
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo [SMTG] Finished.
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code -1073741819.   test    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   166
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is one of those rare times I think an image might be helpful. That looks like nothing I've ever seen come out of the error list. The full graphical context may be helpful. Make the Error List as big as you can and take a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I added the screenshot. Some information that might be useful, while installing visual studio, I didn't install the whole C++ package, maybe something is missing.

Comment: I have no clue what that is, but hopefully someone does. All I can tell you is one of the tools threw an access violation (-1073741819-> C0000005 -> Access violation).